# How to use multiprocessing.pool, multiprocessing.event and multiprocessing.terminate to run this particular program

Tags: python, event-handling, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I have written a dummy code to understand how multiprocessing.event, multiprocessing.wait and multiprocessing.terminate works. Here I want to find the squares of all the numbers in the list. And I have a target set. When the square of a number gives the target in any one of the multiple process running in parallel, I want the program to terminate all the parallel process but continue the loop and go to the next list of numbers to do the same. I hope you understand what I mean.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Event


def square(no, target, found_event):

    x=no**2
    print(no,x)
    if x == target:
        print('Found')
        found_event.set()

def func_for_args(args):
    """
    Function to create pointer of arguments for pool
    """
    return square(*args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ncpu = 2
    l=[]
    l.insert(0,[2,3])
    l.insert(1,[1,6])
    l.insert(2,[5,4,7,8])

    target = 25
    found_event = Event()

    for i  in range(3):
        print('Run',i)

        pool=Pool(ncpu)
        args=[(no,target,found_event) for no in l[i]]
        pool.map(func_for_args,args)

        found_event.wait() 

        for p in pool:
            p.close()
            p.terminate()
            p.join()
```